# problem Vuexy with RTL in booststrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js

when changing the direction of Vuexy from ltr to rtl. bootstrap-vue data picker style will fail as illustrated [image]in attachment image

Comment: This might be better filed in the [Bootstrap-Vue GitHub repo](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues). As-is, it's not really detailed enough as a question for Stack Overflow. Can you provide us a [MRE]?

Comment: this is clear for Vuexy users. plz check this link  https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/forms/form-element/timepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.custom-timePicker {
  width: max-content;
  right: 0px !important;
}

[dir=rtl] .custom-timePicker {
  right: 0px !important;
}
```

add to style.scss